# In Access 2002, how can I transfer databases from multiple oracles sources?

Tags: oracle, ms-access, vba

I have some simple VBA to import tables from multiple Oracle databases. I have one ODBC entry, and I connect to different databases using different credentials.

My transfer database code is simple:

`DoCmd.TransferDatabase acImport, "ODBC", "ODBC;DNS=source;UID=user;PWD=pass;", acTable, "SomeRemoteTable", "MyLocalTable", True`

That code works, but when I run the same command with a different user/pass immediatley after this command I get this error:

`Run-time error '3011': The Microsoft Jet database engine could not find the object 'SomeRemoteTable'. Make sure the object exists and that you spell its name and the path name correctly`.

Here's the catch:

The DNS, user credentials, and table names are correct. If I open access and comment either line out, then either transfer will run successfully. However, once one command runs, the other will not run until Access has been closed and reopened.

I'm guessing that there must be a way to close the first connection before proceeding to the next. Does anyone have any ideas on what I can try?

Comment: to be clear, I can run multiple TransferDatabase commands, but with only one set of credentials. If I want to run TransferDatabase commands with alternate credentials, I have to restart access, then run them.

Comment: Waiting does not seem to have any effect. Not sure if this is of interest, but I can successfully run the original TransferDatabase command after getting the error, so the first connection is still available/working.

Comment: Yeah, it seems Access "remembers" the user credentials (plus additional information?) from the previous attempt (maybe previous successful attempt?) and tries to re-use that remembered information.  And re-starting Access causes it to lose that memory.  I've never run into this before.  I might try a new DAO Workspace session for the TransferDatabase with different user credentials.  I don't know whether that would bring joy.

Comment: Something else to consider is it might be a Oracle DB setting/issue.  If the ODBC connection is never truly is flushed, the DB Engine (Oracle) might be getting confused that its sending new credentials for an existing connection?  I'm not sure if that can be fixed on access' side.  ADO/DAO might be a better alternative since you have more connection control.

Answer (score 0):

If the databases are owned by you how about setting up a dblink on one of them to the other ?
You will then only need 1 connection.

Comment: Unfortunately the databases aren't owned by my me, and changing anything on the database end isn't an option.

Comment: I had a feeling you were going to say that. Have you tried connecting using 2 DSN's